# Is perovskite symmetric under exchange of A and B atoms?

Tags: crystal-structure, symmetry

A [perovskite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perovskite_(structure)) is any crystal with the general formula $\ce{ABX3}$ where if the $\ce{B}$ atoms form a cube, an $\ce{A}$ atom sits in its center and the $\ce{X}$ atoms sit between neighboring $\ce{B}$ atoms.

Is the perovskite structure symmetric under exchange of $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ atoms? That is, if I replace every $\ce{A}$ atom with a $\ce{B}$ atom and vice versa, will I end up with the same exact structure as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  In the [perovskite structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perovskite_(structure)), the "A" atoms are larger than the "B" atoms.  The B atoms are 6-fold coordinated, while the "A" atoms are in 12-fold [cuboctohedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron) coordination.

Comment: I'd say the size is not the reason - the coordination/symmetry difference does the job to explain why the sites are not equivalent. The larger volume available in that center certainly helps explain why a larger atom likes it, but if it can't hack the coordination requirements it won't want to be a perovskite.